# Proof that any unit-speed-reparametrization of a curve preserves orientation and is an inverse of an arc length function based at some $t_0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I am not able to prove the following two facts about a unit speed reparametrization of a curve.

1. Let $\alpha$ be defined on some interval $I$ and define for $t_0\in I$
   $$\lambda_{t_{0}}(t)=\int_{t_0}^t\|\alpha'(x)\|\,dx.$$ 
   Any unit-speed-reparametrization (usp) $\phi_{t_{0}}$ is then given by 
   $$\phi_{t_{0}}=\lambda_{t_{0}}^{-1}.$$
2. Any unit speed reparametrization preserves orientation.

I think the facts assume that any usp $h$ is a diffeomorphism, but I'm not sure where this comes from. I would appreciate any explanations on the above facts.

My question arose from the same problem as the one from the possible duplicate question, however, the answer in that did not explain the above two, which I don't have a justification for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit speed reparametrization of curve](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498238/unit-speed-reparametrization-of-curve)

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I looked at the answer and that's where I got the above questions. You said they were basic facts, but I can't prove them.

Comment: Well, obviously (1) defines all usp parametrizations of the curve; there's nothing to prove.  And hence, by construction, all usp preserve orientation.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Sorry but I don't see how it is obvious. It's saying that any usp $h$ must be an inverse of some arc length parametrization. How is this clear?

Comment: What else should a usp be?!

Comment: Isn't a usp simply a regular curve with speed 1?

Comment: And hence arc-length parametrized .