# Proof that Curvature is independent of Parametrization

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

One of my online calculus lectures asked, to be completed as an exercise, why two arc length parametrization yield the same curvature. Specifically it asks, if $C$ is a curve and $\mathbf{r}_1(s)$ and $\mathbf{r}_2(t)$ are two arc length parameterizations of C, and $\mathbf{r}_1(s_0)$ and $\mathbf{r}_2(t_0)$ correspond to some point P on C, then
$$\| \mathbf{r}_1''(s_0) \| = \| \mathbf{r}_2''(t_0) \|.$$
I tried deriving relationships from the definition that an arc length function satisfies and was able to obtain that if s and t are functions of some u that
$$s'(u)=t'(u)$$
such that
$$s(u)=t(u)+c.$$
I've gone in multiple directions to try to prove something that seems so simple, and I feel as though I am missing a certain relationship between the two parameterizations that the problem implies. Can anyone point me in the right direction to try and prove this? It seems like I'm way overthinking this problem.

Comment: You're using $s(u)$ and $t(u)$ as an example. $s$ and $t$ are different functions but of the same variable $u$. What you're trying to show is that if $\mathbf{r}_1(s_0)$ and $\mathbf{r}_2(t_0)$ correspond to the same point $P$ on $C$, namely if

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{r}_1(s_0) = \mathbf{r}_2(t_0)
\end{equation}

then $\| \mathbf{r}_1''(s_0) \| = \| \mathbf{r}_2''(t_0) \|$.

Does this not just follow from differentiating both sides of the equality $\mathbf{r}_1(s_0) = \mathbf{r}_2(t_0)$ twice?

Comment: @JacobCheverie Considering that $\mathbf{r}_1(s_0)$ and $ \mathbf{r}_2(t_0) $ are simply vectors and not vector-valued functions, I'm not sure if they can be differentiated

Comment: $\mathbf{r}_1(s)$ and $\mathbf{r}_2(t)$ are given as arc length parameterizations. They are vector functions which can be differentiated. The form they gave the solution in has the vector functions being differentiated twice. Do you see now that they can be differentiated?

For example, let $\mathbf{r}(s) = 3s^2-s$. That can certainly be differentiated with respect to $s$, or $t$ if $s$ is a parameterization of $t$.

Comment: @JacobCheverie are the functions themselves actually equal to each other? That's what I've been debating

Comment: The two different parameterizations are representing the same curve. Essentially what the equation you're unsure about is saying, is that the second derivative of arc length is the same no matter which way you parameterize the curve. This makes sense since both parameterizations have to be the same if they represent the same curve.

Comment: @JacobCheverie: I don't think you can get this just by differentiating both sides twice. If we could do that, we wouldn't have used the fact that they were arc length parameterizations. We'll have to use that somehow.

Comment: @EliRose, you are correct. You cannot obtain that relationship by what I said in my first comment. $\mathbf{r}_1(s_0)$ will return a constant value. Refer to my last comment to see what's going on here. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: @JacobCheverie: Right, I agree that's what's going on at a high level, and that's how I understand it as well. But now I'm curious about the proof.

Comment: @JacobCheverie: I don't agree that two parameterizations have to be the same if they represent the same curve; one could draw out the curve from back to front, and the other from front to back (then they would be negatives of each other). What I don't know is, for arc-length parameterizations, if those are the only options.

Comment: @EliRose You're totally correct. However, since the two parameterizations correspond at point $P$ on $C$, the curvature is the same at that point. All that needs to be done here, and I'm not saying it's easy, is to compute the expression  for curvature corresponding to each parameterization. Then show that the expressions are equal at $P$, probably using the fact that since there are two parameterizations, there exists a function $f$ such that $\mathbf{r}_1(s) = \mathbf{r}_2(f(t))$.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the last but one sentence of [Unit speed reparametrization of curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498238/unit-speed-reparametrization-of-curve/499710#499710) you know that there exists a constant $c$ such that $ r(s+c)=r(t)$.

Comment: Thank you -- this is the result I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Answer outdated, please see Michael Hoppe's suggestion.

Here's a proof that's missing one step of rigor, which I cooked up with the help of a suggestion from JacobCheverie. I'll use the product rule for vector-valued functions, which is:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \mathbf{f}(x) \cdot \mathbf{g}(x) = \mathbf{f}'(x) \cdot \mathbf{g}(x) + \mathbf{f}(x) \cdot \mathbf{g}'(x)$$

Assume that both $\mathbf{r_1}(s)$ and $\mathbf{r_2}(t)$ are differentiable. Then there must be some $f(s) = t$ (a way to convert between parametrizations) and because both are arc-length parametrizations

$$f(s_0) = \pm 1$$

(at the shared point, either they are the same, or going in opposite directions). I'm not sure what the nicest way to show this is.

Assuming that, starting from $||\mathbf{r_1}'(s)|| = ||\mathbf{r_2}'(t)||$, square both sides to get

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{r_1}'(s) \cdot \mathbf{r_1}'(s) &= \mathbf{r_2}'(t) \cdot \mathbf{r_2}'(t)\\
\mathbf{r_1}'(s) \cdot \mathbf{r_1}'(s) &= \mathbf{r_2}'(f(s)) \cdot \mathbf{r_2}'(f(s))\\
\frac{d}{ds} \left(\mathbf{r_1}'(s) \cdot \mathbf{r_1}'(s)\right) &= \frac{d}{ds} \left(\mathbf{r_2}'(f(s)) \cdot \mathbf{r_2}'(f(s))\right)\\
2(\mathbf{r_1}''(s) \cdot \mathbf{r_1}'(s)) &= 2f'(s)(\mathbf{r_2}''(f(s)) \cdot \mathbf{r_2}'(f(s)))\\
\mathbf{r_1}''(s) \cdot \mathbf{r_1}'(s) &= f'(s)(\mathbf{r_2}''(f(s)) \cdot \mathbf{r_2}'(f(s)))\\
||\mathbf{r_1}''(s)|| ||\mathbf{r_1}'(s)|| &= f'(s)^2||\mathbf{r_2}''(f(s))|| ||\mathbf{r_2}'(f(s)))||\\
||\mathbf{r_1}''(s)|| &= f'(s)^2||\mathbf{r_2}''(f(s))||\\
||\mathbf{r_1}''(s_0)|| &= f'(s_0)^2||\mathbf{r_2}''(t_0)||\\
||\mathbf{r_1}''(s_0)|| &= ||\mathbf{r_2}''(t_0)||\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Can anyone help me with $f'(s)$? I actually don't know why $f'(s) \ne \pm 1$ in general, for all $s$ -- if we're assuming differentiable arc-length $\mathbf{r_1}$ and $\mathbf{r_2}$, it seems like the they must either be the same or be opposite to each other.

If they weren't differentiable, I see how one could suddenly change direction any number of times (covering the same ground over and over again), but keep the same speed. But for arc-length parameterizations, does any such reversal in direction have to be non-differentiable?

Comment: How did you get from $$\mathbf{r_1}''(s) \cdot \mathbf{r_1}'(s) = f'(s)(\mathbf{r_2}''(f(s)) \cdot \mathbf{r_2}'(f(s)))$$ to
$$||\mathbf{r_1}''(s)|| ||\mathbf{r_1}'(s)|| = f'(s)^2||\mathbf{r_2}''(f(s))|| ||\mathbf{r_2}'(f(s)))||?$$

Comment: @MatthewPereira: Take the length of both sides -- oops, that wouldn't give you $f'(s)^2$, now would it? This should be redone using Michael Hoppe's suggestion, but unfortunately I don't have the time right now.

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand how you can take the separate the magnitude of two quantities in a dot product. Other than that this makes sense so thanks!

Comment: @MatthewPereira: You are correct, I for some reason was acting as if $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} = ||\mathbf{u}||||\mathbf{v}||$ when it actually equals $\cos{(\theta)}||\mathbf{u}||||\mathbf{v}||$. And when I said "the length of both sides" that was inaccurate, I just meant to use the result above.

Comment: @MatthewPereira: Ah-ha, that factor of $\cos(\theta)$ must be why this is only true at $s = s_0 = t_0$! The derivative $f'(s)$ is always $1$, but we have to use the fact that the acceleration vectors coincide when the parameterizations coincide to get rid of that factor.