# On the definition of curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

Let $\gamma:(\alpha,\beta)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a smooth regular curve. To define the curvature of $\gamma$ at the parameter value $t \in (\alpha,\beta)$, we take a smooth unit-speed reparametrization $\delta:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ (with $\gamma=\delta \circ \phi$, where $\phi:(\alpha,\beta)\rightarrow (a,b)$ is a diffeomorphism) and take the quantity $||\ddot \delta(\phi(t))||$ to be such curvature.

How can I show that this definition doesn't depend on the reparametrization? That is, how can I show that if I take another smooth unit speed curve $\delta_1:(a_1,b_1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and another diffeomorphism $\phi_1:(\alpha,\beta)\rightarrow (a_1,b_1)$ such that $\gamma = \delta_1 \circ \phi_1$, I have $||\ddot\delta(\phi(t))||=||\ddot\delta_1(\phi_1(t)||?$

Comment: Good question. Show that the two diffeomorphisms can differ only by a translation (by a fixed real number).

Comment: @TedShifrin I managed to prove that $\phi_1 = \pm \phi_2 + c$ where $c$ is a fixed constant. It was easy to conclude from that.

Comment: The orientation is usually part of the description (going from $\alpha$ to $\beta$), so should not have the sign ambiguity.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498238/unit-speed-reparametrization-of-curve/499710#499710